# Skrollr Destroy at width AND mobile devices

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, parallax, skrollr

I'm using the the Skrollr destroy method to kill skrollr on anything under 768px.

Found this on here and it mostly works great:

```js
$(function () {
  // initialize skrollr if the window width is large enough
  if ($(window).width() > 767) {
    skrollr.init(yourOptions);
  }

  // disable skrollr if the window is resized below 768px wide
  $(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
      skrollr.init().destroy(); // skrollr.init() returns the singleton created above
    }
  });
});
```

But my mobile devices are only partially turning skrollr off. especially the iPad.

I've seen this destroy method on here too:

```js
//function
$(function skrollrInit() {

    //initialize skrollr
    skrollr.init({
        smoothScrolling: false
    });

    // disable skrollr if using handheld device
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        skrollr.init().destroy();
    }

});

//execute function
skrollrInit();
```

I'm wondering if there is a method that combines the two?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

```
if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && $(window).width() > 767) { // only init skrollr on non-mobile devices
    skrollr.init(yourOptions);
}

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // no reason to destroy on mobile
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
          skrollr.init().destroy(); // skrollr.init() returns the singleton created above
        }
    }

});
```